# Accessing form values for use in hidden fields using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three select tags for birthday (day/month/year) that look like this one:

```
<td><%= select_tag(:birth_day, options_for_select((1..31)), {:id => 'select1'}) %></td>
```

I'm trying to access the three values and combine them into a single string and then submit that string using a hidden field. I can't figure out how to get the values to read them into the hidden field.

Right now my best attempt is:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :combined_date, :value => "#{@birth_day}" %>
```

But birth_day just comes through as an empty string. (I'm planning on combining this string with birth_month and birth_year after I get the values to read in).

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: You need to use javascript to set the value of `combined_date` as each of those three `options` get selected.  This however might not be required given that you can combine those three fields in Rails model and if required populate the `combined_date` attribute.  By the way, which one of these attributes are database columns?

Comment: The hidden field value combined_date will be inserted into the database

Comment: Validate the three attributes in model, then on a before_save callback construct your date object using the three attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just combine them when you save the record?

In controller:

```
combined_date: (params[:day]+"/"+params[:month]+"/"+params[:year]).to_date
@record.save
```

It's not elegant, but at least you don't need to use javascript just to unnecessarily combine them on the client side.